# How to access Nested Dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a YAML file that looks like this

```
Title: "COVID-19 Bulletin – Details on key guidances and press releases on COVID-19 (Vol.42 – 15Jan2021)"
Section 1:
  - Title : "What's new in this issue?"
  - Heading 2:
         Title : "North America"
         Heading 3:
           Title: "US guidances/regulations"
           Content :
             - "13-Jan-2021: COVID-19: Potency Assay Considerations for Monoclonal Antibodies and Other Therapeutic Proteins Targeting SARS-CoV-2 Infectivity"

  - Heading 2:
        Title : "Asia-Pacific"
        Heading 3:
          Title: "Canada notices/statements/press releases"
          Content:
            - "11-Jan-2021: Notice: Vaccines and Treatments for COVID-19: Progress, 11-Jan-2021"
            - "08-Jan-2021: Notice: COVID-19 Vaccine Safety-Adverse Events Following Immunization Report, 08-Jan-2021"
```

I need to be able to access contents of Heading 3. When I print it like this:

```
print(section1[1]["Heading 2"]["Heading 3"]["Content"])
```

It prints the output just fine but when I print it in a loop it gives an error

```
for i in range(1, len(section1)):
    heading2 = section1[i]["Heading 2"]["Title"]

    for j in section1[i]["Heading 2"]["Heading 3"]:
        print(j["Title"])
```

It gives out following error:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: do you need always `section1[1]["Heading 2"]["Heading 3"]["Content"]` ? small suggestion you loop direct `for i in section1` , there is no need to calculate len then access through index of  `section1` list

Answer (score 0):

Your inner loop:

```
    for j in section1[i]["Heading 2"]["Heading 3"]:
        print(j["Title"])
```

is iterating over the keys of the dictionary held in "Heading 3", since the body of "Heading 3" is a dictionary (and not a list). So `j` will take on the values of the keys in "Heading 3". So "Title" then "Content" based on the snippet you provided.

If you want to access the title of each "Heading 3", you need not loop, you simply need to access `section1[i]["Heading 2"]["Heading 3"]["Title"]`.